# How to display the file path in Entry widget in windows path format

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have written a Tkinter program in which the **Browse** button is used to select a file and the selected file's complete path gets displayed in the **Entry** widget. But my problem is, it's displaying the path with 'forward'(/) slashes instead of the conventional windows format of 'backward'(\) slashes. This is strange for me since I'm working on windows os. 
Why this occurs ? Is there any before hand fix for this, instead of replace string option ?

my code:

```
def selectfile():
    fileName = askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose a file', initialdir='C:\\')       
    custName.set(fileName) #Populate the text field with the selected file

#create the 'filepath' field
custName = StringVar(None)
filepath = Entry(root, width ='50', textvariable=custName).pack(anchor=W)

#Create the 'Browse' button
browseButton = Button(root, text="Browse", relief = 'raised', width=8, command=selectfile, cursor='hand2').place(x=325,y=16)
```

Expected Output in Entry widget:

```
c:\data\file.txt
```

Actual Output in Entry widget:

```
c:/data/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use replace() to replace "/" with "\" for string. Here's link with docs about replace() method:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=replace#string.replace

This is workaround fix. Try looking more deeply inside Tkinter's docs for actual answer why this occurs.

Comment: I'm already aware of this fix but my intent is to know why this occurs(didn't find any explanation in Tkinter docs) and if I could fix this before hand, before displaying in the Entry widget.